# Find the next non blank value in SAS

Tags: sas, linear-interpolation

I am trying to linearly interpolate values within a panel set data. So I am find the next non zero value within a variable if the current value of the variable is "."

For example if X = { 1, 2, . , . , . ,7), I want to store 7 as a variable "Y" and subject the lag value of X from it as the numerator of the slope. Can anyone help with this step?

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot transpose your data, here is a way that will work for your given example:

```
data test;
    input id $3. x best12.;
    datalines;
AAA 1
BBB 2
CCC .
DDD .
EEE .
FFF 7
;
run;

data test2;
    set test;
    n = _n_;
    if x ne .;
run;

data test3;
    set test2;
    lagx = lag(x);
    lagn = lag(n);
    if _n_ > 1 and n ne lagn + 1 then do;
        postiondiff = n - lagn;
        valuediff = x - lagx;
        do i = (lagx + ((x-lagx)/(n-lagn))) to x by ((x-lagx)/(n-lagn));
            x = i;
            output;
        end;
    end;
    else output;
    keep x;
run;

data test4;
    merge test test3 (rename = (x=newx));
run;
```

So we are basically rebuilding the variable with the interpolated values, then remerging it into the original dataset without a by variable which will line up all the new interpolated data with the missing points.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a way you could transpose all your data? Interpolating like that is much easier when all the data you need is in a single observation. Like this:

```
data test;
input x best12.;
datalines;
1
2
.
.
.
7
;
run;

proc transpose data = test
  out = test2;
run;

data test3;
    set test2;
    array xvalues {*} COL1-COL6;
    array interpol {4,10} begin1-begin10 end1-end10 begposition1-begposition10 endposition1-endposition10;

    rangenum = 1;
* Find the endpoints of the missing ranges;
do i = 1 to dim(xvalues);
    if xvalues{i} ne . then lastknownx = xvalues{i};
    else do;
        interpol{1,rangenum} = lastknownx;
        if interpol{3,rangenum} = . then interpol{3,rangenum} = i - 1;
    end;

    if i > 1 and xvalues{i} ne . then do;
        if xvalues{i-1} = . then do;
            interpol{2,rangenum} = xvalues{i};
            interpol{4,rangenum} = i;
            rangenum = rangenum + 1;
        end;
    end;
end;

* Interpolate;

rangenum = 1;

do j = 1 to dim(xvalues);
    if xvalues{j} = . then do;
        xvalues{j} = interpol{1,rangenum} + (j-interpol{3,rangenum})*((interpol{2,rangenum}-interpol{1,rangenum})/(interpol{4,rangenum}-interpol{3,rangenum}));
    end;
    else if j > 1 and xvalues{j} ne . then do;
        if xvalues{j-1} = . then rangenum = rangenum + 1;
    end;
end;

keep col1-col6;

run;
```

That can handle up to 10 different missing ranges per observation, though you could tweak the code to handle much more than that by creating bigger arrays.

Answer (score 0):

The SAS data step reads a dataset one record at a time from top to bottom. So at record i, it can't access i+1 because it hasn't read it yet; it can only access i-1. Assume you have a dataset with a variable x.

```
data intrpl;
    retain _x;
    set yourdata;
    by x notsorted;
    if not missing(x) then do;
        _x = x;
        if last.x then do;
            slope = _x - lag(_x);
            output;
        end;
    end;
run;
```

Transposing can get kind of messy if x takes on a lot of values, so I recommend this method. I hope it helps!